# Field2 can be editable only when field1 have filled with only few values(restricted values) in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Field2 can be editable when field1 is filled with few values like 'ADT, ADF, GOV'. So for those three values only in Field1, we can enable the field2 otherwise it should be disabled in MVC.

I have been using custom validation on class level on Model. How can i implement this in jquery/clientside on fly? Please provide me some example if possible.

Thanks

Code:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustomValidatorsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
           //validation code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {

    $("#text1").keyup(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === "ADT") {
            $("#text2").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else { $("#text2").prop("disabled", true); }

    });
});
```